# how to read the 1st column of a table as string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For example, let's say I have code (in Python 3.5) looks like this:

```
In [234]: from io import StringIO
In [235]: f = '#a b c\n08 1 2\n9 3 4\n'
In [236]: df = pd.read_table(StringIO(f), sep=' ')
In [237]: df
Out[237]:
   #a  b  c
0   8  1  2
1   9  3  4
```

It reads the 1st column as `int` and gets rid of `0` before `8`. I know we can pass `dtype={'#a': str}` to read it as str. However, supposedly I don't know the column name before hand, how can I read the 1st column as str type?

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str` from the third line when trying to run your code on Python 2.7.

Comment: not tested on py2. I ran on py3. updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `dtype` with a dictionary where keys correspond to index locations:

```
from io import StringIO
f = '#a b c\n08 1 2\n9 3 4\n'
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(f), sep=' ', dtype={0: str})

print(df)

    #a  b   c
0   08  1   2
1   9   3   4

print(df.dtypes)

#a    object
b      int64
c      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: @RNA Updated to your requirement.

Comment: @jezrael When renaming a column of the input data to 0, it still works because column names are provided as strings within the dtype dictionary whereas integers correspond to index locations.